# Testing that an Activity has been started with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, robolectric

Robolectric allows testing that an `Activity` has been started using `shadowOf(activity).peekNextStartedActivity()`. However, this method doesn't seem to work if the `Activity` is started with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. This is intuitive since the purpose of this flag is not to start a new `Activity` but to bring an existing `Activity` in back stack to front. Is there any way to test this scenario?

**UPDATE**

My testing scenario is the following:

There are 3 Activities involved, let's call them A, B and C. Activity under test is B, which was started by A. B now starts C for result, and when the result is received goes back to A using the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag. Even though there is no Activity A in the stack at that time, I'm expecting it to be started and be available via `peekNextStartedActivity()`.

Answer (score 6):

whenever you send an intent from activity (for instance), you can use the set flags method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | SOME_OTHER_FLAGS...);
startActivity(i);
```

on the resulted activity (SomeActivity in the example) you can use getIntent method:

```
getIntent().getFlags()
```

so the real question is: how to split back the flags into their basic components (bitwise OR)

based on this article: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301

simply check the flags with the component you need

```
if ((getIntent().getFlags() & FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) != 0)
{
     // do something here
}
```

Comment: In my case I would be happy even with checking that the Activity has been started via checking its ComponentName, however, peekNextStartedActivity() doesn't return the correct Activity if I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to start it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried test:

```
private void checkMainActivityIsStarted()
{
    activity.showMainActivity();

    Intent intent = shadowOf( activity ).getNextStartedActivity();
    assertThat( intent ).hasComponent( Robolectric.application, MainActivity.class );
    assertThat( intent.getFlags() ).isEqualTo( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
}
```

For the next code:

```
public void showMainActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

Does it work for you?

**UPDATE**

As for me you should split this test into two:

1. Activity C is returning correct result code
2. Activity B when you call `onActivityResult` (it is public method) fires activity A

As for me there is no sense to test Android passing intents between activities. Correct me if I understood something wrong.

Comment: In my scenario, I'm firing this kind of Intent in onActivityResult(), handling the result sent by another Activity (let's call it A). In test, I start Activity A, receive the result of it and see if it triggered the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP Intent. However, peekNextStartedActivity() (and getNextStartedActivity() as well) gives me the Intent to Activity A.

Comment: I would split it into two tests

Comment: Yes, but AFAIK it's the only way to test onActivityResult()

Comment: I probably don' understand completely what is test code. So you starting A for result which should fire another activity but also return result code. Or B starting A for result, receiving it from A and fires another activity

Answer (score 0):

It definetly solve your problem.

```
  Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | SOME_OTHER_FLAGS...);
    startActivity(i);
```

but If you can finish your current activity at the time of intent from B to C  and When it shows the result and Finish C activity it def takes you on A screen.